# How to add SVN to Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, svn, visual-studio-2012, visualsvn

I was using Visual Studio 2010 previously, with visual SVN as the source control. Now that I've upgraded to Visual Studio 2012, I'm facing problem of adding SVN as the source control (to VS 2012). By default only Team Foundation is there. Any help with how to add SVN as the source control to Visual Studio 2012 would be really appreciated.

Comment: Were you using the AnkhSVN plugin, or maybe the VisualSVN plugin with Visual Studio 2010 ?

Comment: i used VisualSVN with visual studio 2010.

Comment: @BasavarajHiremath VisualSVN 3.0 supports Visual Studio 2012! See http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/DBD60715-FE57-44B5-ABEA-F18618068C1E

Answer (score 8):

VisualSVN 3.0 supports Visual Studio 2012. You can get it at the [**download page**](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/download/).

Except VS2012 support and a couple of usability and UI improvements VisualSVN 3.0 introduces the new Community License that allows to use VisualSVN for free on non-domain machines (moreover it permits commercial use!). See the [VisualSVN 3.0 Release Notes](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/changes/3.0/).

Answer (score 4):

In VS2012 just go to Tools/Options/Source control and in dropdown "Current source control plug-in" select the needed one (if you already have it installed)

Answer (score 4):

Run the Visual SVN installer again and select 'Modify'
Tick the box that say 'Integration Visual Studio 2012'

and then continue with the installation. Restart VS 2012 and you will see VISUAL SVN on the TOP menu

Answer (score 1):

We use AnkhSVN for VS2012 and lower versions.

Comment: Right now tortise svn installed on my system.We can upgrade to AnkhSVN from tortise or we need install again AnkhSVN.

Comment: I don't know how to add `AnkhSVN` plugin to VS2012,I've ALready install it but i can't see anything in VS2012?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you're using old version of VisualSVN that doesn't support VS2012. Try to install latest VisualSVN 3.0 for Visual Studio 2012 support.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I am using VisualSVN-5.1.4, but I have done this with previous versions.

1. Re-run the installer.
2. Select "Modify", then Next to move to the "Custom Setup" pane.
3. A checkbox list of the installed Visual Studio (VS) versions will appear.
4. Check to VS('s) that apply.
5. Open the targeted VS.
6. Open the "Tools>Options" dialog and select Source Control
7. Select "VisualSVN" from the "Current source control plug-in" combo box.

I first took the "Repair" option but that did not put VisualSVN in the Source Control options list. It didn't hurt but it didn't help, either.

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to run the installer of subversion again and repair the installation.
The installer will register the application in the VS2012 version too.

We had the same problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

What you really need to do is go to Tools -> Options

In the dialog scroll down to Source Control -> plug-in-selections.

There is a drop down that has a list of source controls and you select your SVN controller there (Ankh, Visual, whatever one you want).

This is the same for 2012, 2013 and 2015

Answer (score -1):

Re-run the installer , and during the setup, choose the versions of Visual Studio you want to be available.